# How can i fix SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) in my C code?

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am coding a program in C that reads sentences in a file separated by parentheses, interpret them as "rooms" (don't ask) and append them to dynamically allocated singly linked list structure as dynamically allocated nodes. gdb marked the line in add_to_list(const room_t *room, list *list) function

```c
 current->next = createnode(room);
```

line as one causing SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Here is the code:

```c
void
create_room(char *text, list *list)
{
  unsigned int index;
  color_t color;
  char *description;

  parse_curly_brackets(text, &index, &color);

  room_t *new_room = (room_t *)malloc(sizeof(room_t));
  new_room->index = index;
  new_room->color = color;

  char *ptr = strchr(text, '}');
  if (ptr != NULL)
    {
      ptr = strchr(ptr + 1, '}');
      if (ptr != NULL)
        {
          ptr++; 
          while (*ptr != '\0' && (*ptr == ' ' || *ptr == '\n')) 
            ptr++;

          description = ptr;
          new_room->description = (char *)malloc(strlen(description));
          strcpy(new_room->description, description);
        }
      else
        {
          printf("Second closing curly brace not found\n");
          free(new_room);
          return;
        }
    }
  else
    {
      printf("Closing curly brace not found\n");
      free(new_room);
      return;
    }

  add_to_list(new_room, list);
}

node_t
*createnode (const room_t *room)
{
  node_t *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

  if (!newnode)
    {
      return NULL;
    }
  
  newnode->data = room;
  newnode->next = NULL;

  return newnode;
};

void
add_to_list (const room_t *room, list *list)
{
  node_t *current = NULL;

  if (list->head == NULL)
    {
      list->head = createnode(room);
    }

  else
    {
      current = list->head;
      while (current->next != NULL)
        {
          current = current->next;
        }
      current->next = createnode(room);
    }
}
```

Here are the structures:

```c
typedef
struct List
{
  struct Node *head;
  
} list;

typedef
struct Node
{
  const struct Room *data;
  struct Node *next;
} node_t;

typedef
struct Room
{
  unsigned int index;
  color_t color;
  list objects;
  char *description;  /* the description buffer that will be written from the file */
  
} room_t;
```

I tried to make some function arguments const to provide read-only access, but i am not sure if i made it worse. I've checked if i allocated memory correctly, but i can't find what's causing the issue. So i hope you will! you can familiarize yourself with the full code here: https://github.com/stakhovyak/agorica you can check description.org file to understand what am i trying to do in create_room function

Comment: a good day to start using a debugger!

Comment: In C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: A debugger, yes, plus memory checking tools like AddressSanitizer or valgrind.

Comment: i already use valgrind and gdb to test my programs and debug them, the thing is that is my first big project, valgrind shows no problems by the way, i have just rewritten some code from scratch and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You do not allocate room for the null terminator:

```
          new_room->description = (char *)malloc(strlen(description));
          strcpy(new_room->description, description);
```

You need to allocate one more byte:

```
          new_room->description = malloc(strlen(description) + 1);
          strcpy(new_room->description, description);
```

Also, don't cast results of `malloc`.

Comment: that didn't help, unfortunately.. but thanks for the advice!